# Find range of $f(x) = 1-x-2\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's easy to see in a graph calculator that range is $(-1,\infty)$ but I'm not being able to prove it.

I tried to take $x \in Dom(f)$ and show that

- When $x \leq 0, f(x) \geq 1$ using de the fact that $f$ is decreasing there. Or using another simpler function $s(x)$ which $Rng(f) = Rng(d)$ and $s(x) \leq f(x)$ in that range.
- When $x \geq 1, -1 \leq f(x) \leq 0$ using de the fact that $f$ is increasing there. Or using another simpler function $s(x)$ which $Rng(f) = Rng(d)$ and $s(x) \leq f(x)$ in that range.

Is that the easiest way to do this? do you have a nicer/more elegant (subjectively speaking) way to do this? could you recommend me any material to learn how to solve problems like this (or harder)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Infinity should not be included in the range.

Comment: @CroCo corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

If we let $t = \sqrt{1 - x}$, it results that

\begin{align*}
f(x) = 1 - x - 2\sqrt{1 - x} = t^{2} - 2t
\end{align*}

From then on, I assume you can proceed.

Comment: honestly, I don't know how to proceed , I don't know how making $f$ a composition in that way would be a hint

Comment: @sankiago To determine the range of the proposed function, notice that

$$t^{2} - 2t = (t^{2} - 2t + 1) - 1 = (t - 1)^{2} - 1 \geq -1$$

Comment: @sankiago you can check the range of a quadratic equation by completing the square.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia thaanks, any material that you would recommend me to learn to "see" solutions like this in this topic?

Comment: @sankiago Any book about elementary algebra should do the job. I particularly recommend you the book Solving Problems in Algebra and Trigonometry by Litvinenko and Mordkovich.